# How can I access routes object from React Router v6 in a service without a circular dependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, circular-dependency, rtk-query

I'm using an RTK Query service to grab routes from an API. The API returns a path starting with `/` and does not include the base URL. The base URL for an endpoint depends on if that page has been migrated to the SPA. So I want to check the routes in the SPA: If the routes object contains the path for that link, I'll treat the link based on SPA Routing, otherwise I'll add the base URL of the legacy application.

I was disappointed to find that [React Router v6](https://reactrouter.com/en/main) doesn't seem to provide access to its internal routes object. There is a `matchRoutes` function, so I need access to the routes object, but that was in main. So I refactored it to routes.js:

```
import App from "./app";
import ErrorPage from "./pages/error";
import FunctionalityPage from "./pages/examplefunctionality";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/func",
        element: <FunctionalityPage />,
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default routes;
```

Then I import this into main.jsx and pass it to a `RouterProvider`:

```
import store from "./store";
import routes from "./routes";
// ... skipped for brevity
const router = sentryCreateBrowserRouter(routes, {
  basename: import.meta.env.BASE_URL,
});

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Then I'm able to import it in my RTK Query `service.js` as well:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery, retry } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { matchRoutes } from "react-router-dom";
import { routes } from "../routes";

const baseQuery = retry(
  fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_API_URL,
  })
);

export const service = createApi({
  reducerPath: "serviceApi",
  baseQuery,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getMenu: builder.query({
      query: () => `menu/getmenuitems`,
      transformResponse: (data) => {
        const updateHref = (item) => {
          if (item.href) {
            const match = matchRoutes(routes, item.href);
            if (match && match.length > 0) {
              item.to = item.href;
              delete item.href;
            } else {
              item.href = import.meta.env.VITE_LEGACY_URL + item.href;
            }
          }
          if (item.children) {
            item.children.forEach(updateHref);
          }
        };
        data.forEach(updateHref);
        return data;
      },
    }),
    getData: // ... skipped for brevity
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetMenuQuery,
  useGetDataQuery,
} = service;
```

Functionally, this worked perfectly: I'm able to navigate to either the SPA with a Link or the legacy site with an href, by passing this structure into my component. The trouble starts when I run eslint: I get an error from import/no-cycle in `app.jsx`, `examplefunctionality.jsx`, `routes.jsx`, and `service.js`, because ExampleFunctionality imports `getDataQuery` from `service.js`, which therefore imports the routes, which imports the app, and the cycle continues.

Do I have to split up the api service? Ideally I'd like to just have the one API service, since its all connecting to the same API and the RTK Query docs [recommend](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi) that approach. Is this a normal pattern? How should I structure my code to avoid the circular dependency, and maintain the organization?

What I really want is a hook that will expose the actual routes object from the router.

Comment: I've had to solve a similar issue involving a dependency cycle by code splitting the API slice into the base slice and endpoints. Is this enough confirmation or do you need to see an example?

Comment: an example would be very helpful

Comment: @DrewReese what I don't understand is how code splitting would resolve the circular dependency?